# Setting up a MongoDB connection in AngularJS project

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I really don't want to have to install a full-blown MEAN project just for the one piece of data I want to store in MongoDB - is there a way for me to easily set up a MongoDB connection that I can use a service/factory with?

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course!
Mongodb provide a suitable http rest interface.Please find this link:
[MongoDB Rest API](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/)
Just you should run mongod by --rest parameter